# JavaFX como fechar um AnchorPane interno

Tags: java, javafx

Olá pessoal minha duvida é tenho uma AnchorPane filho que é adicionado dentro do AnchorPane pai no meu AnchorPane filho eu tenho um botão chamado fecharAnchorPane meu problema.

Como faço para fechar o AnchorPane filho sem fechar o AnchorPane pai?

meu código está assim:

```
@FXML
private Button btnFacharAnchorPane;

@FXML
public void fachar() {
    btnFecharAnchorPane.getScene().getWindow().hide();
}
```

quando eu clico no botão ele fechar o programa todo, o que eu quero é que ele fecha apenas o AnchorPane interno que é o filho

Comment: o que está acontecendo aí, é que ambos `AnchorPane`, pertenecem ao mesmo `Stage`; na hora de fazer `btnFecharAnchorPane.getScene().getWindow().hide();` vc tá chamando ao mesmo `Stage`

Comment: então como é que faço para fechar o anchorpane interno filho sem fechar o anchorpane pai você sabe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vc pode usar o método `setVisible()` para ocultar e mostrar o `AnchorPane`, no action do button `fecharPane()` só deve adicionar o seguinte

```
        @FXML
        public void fecharPane(ActionEvent evt){
          filho.setVisible(false);
        }
```

Comment: esse aí, é uma das formas do que vc tá querendo fazer, outra sería, criar um novo `Stage` para esse `AnchorPane`, nesse caso vai abrir outra janela.

Comment: valeu funcionou do jeito que eu queria, mais agora você poderia me explicar o que exatamente o método setVisible() faz, você disse que ele oculta o anchorpane mais e esse eu abri o anchorpane uma 30 vezes e nessas 30 vezes eu ocultar ele eu quero saber o anchorpane vai ser fechar de verdade ou as 30 vezes que eu abri ele ainda esta aberto mais só não estou vendo se for esse o caso isso pode causa um pouco de lentidão no programa

Comment: o método `setVisible(boolean value)`, ele simplesmente oculta ou mostra o elemento, vai depender do valor de tipo `boolean`, não vai ter problemas fechar 30 ou 40 vezes, ele já foi carregado na memoria, só vai se ocultar ou se mostrar, outra vantagem desse método é que uma vez seja `false` não permitirá nenhum `action` no elemento.

Comment: valeu mesmo agora entendi muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Para fazer isso você deve atribuir um ID ao AnchorPane pai e modificar seu método conforme o código abaixo:

```
@FXML
private AnchorPane pai;

// [...]

@FXML
public void fecharPane(ActionEvent event){
    // Remove do array de filhos o pane que contém o botão
    pai.getChildren().remove(mybutton.getParent());
}
```

Resultado: (AnchorPane pai em azul e filho em vermelho)

[image: Removendo AnchorPane filho]

Comment: eu tentei fazer mais deu um erro

Comment: No código deixei claro que o AnchorPane era o pai, e no seu código estava filho ... Ao que parece você atribuiu o ID ao painel errado.

Comment: eu tinha colocado ID ao  AnchorPane pai mas quando coloquei o código pai.getChildren().remove(mybutton.getParent()); o nome "pai" ficou sublinhado de vermelho